# Apache Storm deactivated topologies cause high cpu utilization

Tags: java, jvm, apache-storm

I am having an issue with high cpu usage for deactivated apache storm topologies.  I can reliably re-create the issue using the steps below but I haven't identified the exact cause or a solution yet.

The environment is a storm cluster on which 1 topology is running (The topology is extremely simple, I used the exclamation example).  It is INACTIVE.  Initially there is normal CPU usage.  However, when I kill all topology JVM processes on all supervisors and let Storm restart them again, I find that some time later (~9 hours) the CPU usage per JVM process shoots up to nearly 100%.  I have tested an ACTIVE topology and this does not happen with it.  I have also tested more than one topology and observe the same results when they're in the INACTIVE state.

***Steps to re-create:***

1. Run 1 topology on an Apache Storm cluster
2. Deactivate it
3. Kill **all** topology JVM processes on all supervisors (Storm will restart them)
4. Observe the CPU usage on Supervisors shoots up to nearly 100% for all **INACTIVE** topology JVM processes.

***Environment***

Apache Storm 1.1.0 running on 3 VMs, one nimbus and 2 supervisors.

Cluster Summary:

- Supervisors: 2
- Used Slots: 2
- Available Slots: 38
- Total Slots: 40
- Executors: 50
- Tasks: 50

the topology has 2 workers and 50 executors/tasks (threads).

***Investigation so far:***

Apart from being able to reliably re-create the issue, I have identified, for the affected topology JVM process, the threads using the most CPU.  There are 102 threads total in the process, 97 blocked, 5 IN_NATIVE.  The threads using the most CPU are identical and there are 23 of them (all in BLOCKED state):

```
Thread 28558: (state = BLOCKED)
 - sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) @bci=0 (Compiled frame; information may be imprecise)
 - java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(long) @bci=11, line=338 (Compiled frame)
 - com.lmax.disruptor.MultiProducerSequencer.next(int) @bci=82, line=136 (Compiled frame)
 - com.lmax.disruptor.RingBuffer.next(int) @bci=5, line=260 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.publishDirect(java.util.ArrayList, boolean) @bci=18, line=517 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.access$1000(org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue, java.util.ArrayList, boolean) @bci=3, line=61 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue$ThreadLocalBatcher.flush(boolean) @bci=50, line=280 (Interpreted frame)
 - org.apache.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue$Flusher.run() @bci=55, line=303 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call() @bci=4, line=511 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run() @bci=42, line=266 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) @bci=95, line=1142 (Compiled frame)
 - java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() @bci=5, line=617 (Interpreted frame)
 - java.lang.Thread.run() @bci=11, line=745 (Interpreted frame)
```

I identified this thread by using `jstack` to get a thread dump for the process:

```
jstack -F <pid> > jstack-<pid>.txt
```

and `top` to identify the threads within the process using the most CPU:

```
top -H -p <pid>
```

Has anyone come across this or a similar issue before?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I believe this may be related to a closed Storm Jira Issue      
 ------ https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-503
       
 ------ https://github.com/apache/storm/pull/625#issuecomment-119812763

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue happens because the RingBuffer in a [DisruptorQueue](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v1.1.0/storm-core/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/utils/DisruptorQueue.java) fills up and when publishing threads are trying to claim a slot they effectively get stuck doing LockSupport.parkNanos(1L).
As per my comment on Storm [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-2853?focusedCommentId=16347172&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16347172)